# How can i validate fields which are not in forms(means custom ) field on forms.py?

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to validate fields which are not form fields on form.py..is it possible
here is my model form:

```
class Pay_bills(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
        model = Recharge_request
        fields = ['mobile_no','amount']

def clean_amount(self):
    amount = self.cleaned_data.get('amount', None)
    print(self.cleaned_data.get('amount'))
    if ( amount < 1 ):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter valid amount") 
    return amount
```

and  my html page

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;" id="consumer_no_div">
 <label for="inputFirstName" id="field-label" >Consumer No:</label>
 <div>
{% render_field form.mobile_no class="form-control" placeholder="Customer No"%}
```

```
<div class="form-group" >
  <label> Bill Amount:</label>
  <div>
     {% render_field form.amount class="form-control" placeholder="Amount"%}
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group" >
  <label>Service Provider:</label>
  <div >
       <select required  class="form-control" id="sel1" name="service_provider" name="sel">
      <option value="">Select Service Provider</option>
          {%for provider in ser_provider%}
              <option value="{{provider.id}}">{{provider}}</option>
           {%endfor%}
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

here i want to validate service provider which is not my form field ..can i do it on forms.py??thanks in advance

Comment: or can i get value of field using "request.POST.get("service_provider")" on forms.py

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it a form field then?

```
class Pay_bills(forms.ModelForm):
    service_provider = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ser_providers)  # or ModelChoiceField(queryset=ser_providers)

    class Meta:
        model = Recharge_request
        fields = ['mobile_no','amount']

    def clean_service_provider(self):
        ... whatever....
```